# Flickering SCNTube with transparency

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, flicker

**UPDATED**

I create some SCNTubes with following materials:

```
let radius: CGFloat = 0.3
let height: CGFloat = 0.5
let color: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.17, green:0.62, blue:0.76, alpha:1.0)

let geometryTube = SCNTube(innerRadius: (radius - 0.1), outerRadius: radius, height: height)
let matOuter = SCNMaterial()
matOuter.diffuse.contents = color
matOuter.transparency = 0.1
let matInner = SCNMaterial()
matInner.diffuse.contents = color
matInner.transparency = 0.6
let matTop = SCNMaterial()
matTop.diffuse.contents = color
geometryTube.materials = [matOuter, matInner, matTop]

for index in 0...20 {
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometryTube)
    node.position = SCNVector3(1.0 + Double(index), -1.0, 0.0);
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)    
}
```

Depending on the angle the tubes are flickering.

Comment: When you say your tube is flickering between "these two views", you mean small and large (or far and near)?  Your code works fine in my sample I just made.  Please post the part where you are adding the Node and the camera setup.  Your problem is there.

Comment: You are right. I created a plain new project to reproduce the problem with just that code. But I couldn't reproduce it. I will update the solution if I find the cause.

Comment: I could reproduce my problem, see the updated version of the Question.

Answer (score 1):

*The `materials` property is designed to have one `material` for each `geometry` - whereas you are assigning three materials to a single geometry.
These are all overlapping and `scenekit` is having to decide what to render at each point.*

EDIT: My answer (above) was wrong - rather than delete it I'll add [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry/1523472-materials) to highlight why I was wrong:

> If a geometry has the same number of materials as it has geometry
>   elements, the material index corresponds to the element index. For
>   geometries with fewer materials than elements, SceneKit determines the
>   material index for each element by calculating the index of that
>   element modulo the number of materials. For example, in a geometry
>   with six elements and three materials, SceneKit renders the element at
>   index 5 using the material at index 5 % 3 = 2.

Apologies to OP for not being helpful with your question.

Comment: This would only be true to a Geometry with one surface e.g. a sphere.. In this case, an SCNTube has 4 potential areas where a material can be applied e.g. it's base, top and outer & inner Surfaces ^________^

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at how your geometry is lit.

For example there are many different types of `lightingModel` properties you can use e.g.

[image]

Try for example to set each materials `.lightingModel` property to `.constant` e.g:

```
matOuter.lightingModel = .constant
```

Another option you may also want to explore `SCNTransparencyMode` as well...